# Load Django Objects Quicker

Tags: python, django, django-models

so I'm working on a Django news aggregator project. A main aspect of the project involves me fetching reddit and twitter posts through their respective APIs, saving the post data to a post model, then loading those model objects onto the page.

This is what I would prefer to do over fetching the data and displaying it directly through the response objects.

Right now, I have two separate timelines of reddit posts, and twitters posts, adjacent to each other on the page. Last time I loaded the page, it took a really long time. This is what the page looks like btw:

[image]

I was hoping someone could explain to me how I can get my page to load faster, and also how to integrate timeline/newsfeed functionality well. Lets say I have over 1500 post objects in my database, I don't want to load all 1500 on the page at one time. I'd like to load like the first 100, then if someone scrolls down the page enough, the next 100 become loaded, etc. Is there an easy/efficient way to go about this?

Thanks

---

EDIT 6/30/21

Here is my code:

**views.py**

```
from .models import Post
from news import services
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404


def mainpage(request):
    all_posts=Post.objects.all()
    context={'posts': all_posts}
    return render(request, "mainpage.html", context)
```

---

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class Post(models.Model):
    # Reddit, Twitter, Youtube
    post_type = models.CharField(
        max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    root_url = models.CharField(max_length=200, default="")
    html = models.TextField(default="")
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

---

**template**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %} {% block content %} {% autoescape off %} {% load red_attempt %} {% load tweet_tags %}
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
  integrity="sha384-eOJMYsd53ii+scO/bJGFsiCZc+5NDVN2yr8+0RDqr0Ql0h+rP48ckxlpbzKgwra6" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">
      <h3 class='text-center'>Twitter News</h3>
      {% for post in posts %}
        {% if post.post_type == 'Twitter' %}
          <div class="mdl-card__media" id="timeline"></div>
              {{ post.html }}
        {% endif %}
      <br>
      {% endfor %}
      <script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
      <h3 class='text-center'>Reddit News</h3>
      {% for post in posts %}
        {% if post.post_type == 'Reddit' %}
          <div class="mdl-card__media" id="timeline"></div>
            {{ post.html }}
        {% endif %}
      <br>
      {% endfor %}
      <script async src="//embed.redditmedia.com/widgets/platform.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
{% endautoescape %}{% endblock %}


<script async src="//embed.redditmedia.com/widgets/platform.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
<script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
  integrity="sha384-JEW9xMcG8R+pH31jmWH6WWP0WintQrMb4s7ZOdauHnUtxwoG2vI5DkLtS3qm9Ekf" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: You can use pagination to load a few objects at a time: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/pagination/

Comment: About the slowness, is it because of loading the posts from the DB or loading the posts from twitter/reddit API?

Comment: In addition to pagination you can add database indexes and prefetch related data

Comment: You should probably add your view / template code to your question to get the most helpful response. It sounds like you're storing the fetches locally in your own DB so I'd probably create an API using DRF. Fetch the most recent X posts and then lazy load more as you scroll. You can also use a cache potentially to store those top X posts (and replace it I guess after each poll to reddit/twitter) to make the initial load faster and save your main DB some work.

Comment: Thanks. I'll read about Pagination to implement it. I don't know much about database indexing and prefetching related data, however. And I'll update with my view and template right now. I figured I would have to implement a cache at some point, I've just never done that before so I'm unfamiliar with the process.